# Compatibility of a metric for a given topological space.

Tags: general-topology

It is indeed a very easy question but I am not %100 sure about it.

Assume you are given a topological space $(X,\tau_x)$ with base $\mathcal B$.

And you are given a metric on $X$. We know that $d$ induces a topological space with base $\mathcal B_d=\{B(x,\epsilon)|x\in X, \text{for some}\quad  \epsilon>0 \}$

Is the problem showing $d$ is compatible with given $(X,\tau_x)$, actually showing the given topological space is equivalent to the induced by $d$?

Comment: Yes. [Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.]

Comment: Yes. And a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is called metrizable if there is a metric $d$ on $X$ which is compatible with $(X,\tau)$..... And  $(X,\tau)$  is called completely  metrizable  if there is a complete metric $d$ on $X$ which is compatible with $(X,\tau)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\mathcal{B}$ induces the  topology $\mathcal{T}_X$ (the original topology on $X$),by taking unions, and a metric $d$ induces a base $\mathcal{B}_d = \{B(x,r): x \in X; r>0\}$.

Your task is then indeed to show that the topology induced by $\mathcal{B}_d$ is also exactly $\mathcal{T}_X$, or any $B \in \mathcal{B}$ is metric open and vice versa. So you need

$$\forall B \in \mathcal{B}: \forall x \in B: \exists r>0: B(x,r) \subseteq B\tag{1}$$

and also

$$\forall x \in X: \forall r>0: \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \subseteq B(x,r)\tag{2}$$